# Locally ringed spaces over field

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Currently studying an article of Koji SEKIGUCHI "Ringed Spaces of Valuation Rings and Projective Limits of Schemes" from [projecteuclid.org](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/tokyo-journal-of-mathematics/volume-16/issue-1/Ringed-Spaces-of-Valuation-Rings-and-Projective-Limits-of-Schemes/10.3836/tjm/1270128992.full) and the author gave in proposition 1 an equivalence:

The following two conditions for a local ringed space (X, $\mathcal{O}_{X}$ ) and a field $k$ are equivalent:

[image: proposition on ringed spaces]

wjere the author talks about an injection between $\mathcal{O}_{X}(V)$ and Map(V,K) whitout mention of the map, so it seems like there is a canonical map.

What does the author mean here?

Comment: [Please do not rely on pictures of math and text](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320052/why-are-images-of-text-code-and-mathematical-expressions-discouraged). Instead, please type up the content of the screenshot using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: By the definition of a morphism of ringed spaces, an element of ${\rm Map}(V,K)$ corresponds to a function $f:V\to {\rm Spec}(K)$ together with a morphism of sheaves of ${\cal O}_K$-modules ${\cal O}_K\to f_*({\cal O}_V)$. Now since ${\rm Spec}(K)$ has only one point, the sheaves of modules on $K$ correspond to $K$-vector spaces and (unravelling the defs) $f_*({\cal O}_V)$ corresponds to the vector space $H^0(V,{\cal O}_V)={\cal O}_V(V)={\cal O}_X(V)$. Also, ${\cal O}_K$ corresponds to $K$. Since there is only one function from $V$ to a point, we see that ...

Comment: ... ${\rm Map}(V,K)$ corresponds to the $K$-linear maps $K\to {\cal O}_X(V)$, which is non other than ${\cal O}_X(V)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for editing the post.

Comment: @KReiser thanks,I am not very familiar with the site rules,it seems ananta edited the post.

Comment: @DamianRössler thanks,so the author mean here by Map(V,K) the  set of morphism of O_{K}-modules between V and K.

Comment: It looks like it would be a the set of morphisms of LRS's from $V$ to $k$.  I find this pretty confusing, since usually when $k$ is viewed as a LRS, it's the affine line $\operatorname{Spec} k[x]$ over $k$. On the other hand, Damian Rössler
is treating it like $\operatorname{Spec} k$ which could also be what the author intended. In any case, I think the author could have been much clearer about this.

Comment: I voted to close because I don't think we can give a proper answer to this question without knowing the definition of $\operatorname{Map}(V, k)$. To not leave you totally without help, here's a concrete and natural way to get a set map. For a section $s \in \mathcal{O}_X(V)$, we can define a map $V \to k$ by sending $v \mapsto [s_{v}] \in \mathcal{O}_{V, v}/\mathfrak{m}_{v}$. (Furthermore, this defines a map of LRH's $V \to \operatorname{Spec} k[x]$).

Comment: @DamianRössler I think your definition of a morphism of LRH's is not quite right. The map of structure sheaves should be a map of $k$-algebras (usually with the convention that $1 \mapsto 1$), so there should only be one $k$-linear map $k \to \mathcal{O}_{X}(V)$, picking out the $1$-section.

Comment: @Daniel. You are quite right! I wrote too fast.